# My Word Addin crashes after IDTExtensibility2"s OnDisconnection method is called

Tags: c++, ms-office, office-addins

My Word Addin's OnDisconnection implementation is crashing when it leaves the method. Word calls this IDTExtensibility2 method when an Addin is removed from Word (that is, unchecked in the COM Addins list). I am looking for ways to debug this, in particular, where I can get mso.pdb so I can get some symbolic debugging info.

Here is my code in the OnDisconnection:

```
AppEvents2::DispEventUnadvise(m_spApp,&__uuidof(ApplicationEvents2));
m_spApp.Release();
```

Commenting out the AppEvents2... line eliminates the crash. Actually, both lines need to be commented out.

Comment: What code do you run in the OnDisconnection method? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

MS apparently doesn't make the mso.pdb symbol file available (see 'How can I get the PDB files about VBE6.dll and MSO.dll?' in Microsoft.public.windbg).

I had to use divide-and-conquer to solve my problem eliminating code in my addin until the problem disappeared. Kind of primitive, but it worked.